# If running MySql on remote is jdbc url host still localhost

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql db running on a remote server. I am trying to use it in a tomcat webapp. My username to log in is still root@localhost, but would the jdbc connection string still be: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/FlashCardShark`? Or would it be at my IP address. I confirmed that the port is 3306 with `show varialbes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at all, if your `tomcat` on machine A, and `mysql` on B, then you must have to specifiy the URL to `jdbc:mysql://B-ip:3306/dbname`.

Comment: thanks I realized my problem is that I did not configure a jndi datasource, that's why my database isn't being used. Not becuase of the connection string.